# extract digits between 2 patterns awk/egrep

Tags: awk, grep

I want to extract the variable number of digits between two patterns, eg:

correction:

```
blah blah.... AAM #6,blah blah

blah blah.... AAM #10 , blah blah

blah blah.... AAM #100 , blah blah
```

output: 6, 10 and 100

I need to extract numbers between `AMA #` and `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two patterns the digits are supposed to be between are `AAM#` and `,`

`gawk 'match($0, /AAM #([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*,/, a) {print a[1]}'`

Comment: I was trying to use this as a part of a larger search and am encountring errors. The cmd is sed -n "/COMPLETE/p" 1.txt | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } {printf"%s %s:%s \n", substr($4,1,10),substr($6,8,1), match($7, /AAM #([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]?,/, a) a[1] }' I am trying to get the digit into 3rd %s of printf and I see that the number is preceeded by a count (2 or 3). Any idea what my mistake is?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
blah blah.... AAM #6,blah blah
blah blah.... AAM #10 , blah blah
blah blah.... AAM #100 , blah blah

$ awk -F'(AAM #| *,)' '{print $2}' file
6
10
100
```

Answer (score 0):

try a regular expression like (?<=#)\d+

Answer (score 0):

No need to use sed if you use awk. Its redundant.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}/COMPLETED/{
  match($7, /AAM #([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]?,/, a)
  printf "%s %s:%s \n", substr($4,1,10),substr($6,8,1),  a[1] 
} ' file
```

Comment: Even better. It has been 15 yrs since I scripted. Tried the above and there is a syntax error at printf. Added {} like so and this gives incorrect results. 

gawk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}/COMPLETED/ { match($7, /AAM #([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]?,/, a) } {printf "%s %s:%s \n", substr($4,1,10),substr($6,8,1), a[1] } ' file

Comment: There is no syntax error in the scrip @ghostdog74 posted, you must have messed up the copy/paste. By adding those parentheses you're moving the printf outside of the block that only gets executed when COMPLETED is found and so significantly changing the script.